# How do I get a random anyobject from an unordered array of anyobject?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's the code I have:

```
if let photosData = parsedResult as? NSDictionary {
    var arrayOfPhotos = photosData.valueForKey("data")!
    // i want to do something like let photo = arrayOfPhotos.random
}
```

where photosData is

```
"data" =    
    (
        { 
            "id"= 1234;
            "name" = "Sam";
        },
        { 
            "id"= 4567;
            "name" = "John";
        },
        { 
            "id"= 1234;
            "name" = "Tony";
        }
    )
```

Now I am left with arrayOfPhotos which took the value of "data"

Questions:

How do I access a random object in arrayOfPhotos?

When I have a variable that xcode doesn't immediately tell me the type of, how do I get the type?

How do I log variables, objects while debugging? Do I just use print?

EDIT2: Heavily edited because the question was poorly written.

**SOLVED:**

I added "as? [AnyObject]" to arrayOfPhotos Declaration

```
if let photosData = parsedResult as? NSDictionary {
    var arrayOfPhotos = photosData.valueForKey("data")! as? [AnyObject]
    // i want to do something like let photo = arrayOfPhotos.random
}
```

now i can grab an object through arrayOfPhotos.first or grab at an index

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary has two keys and associated values. Why are you saying there are no keys?

Comment: Why not instead of making everyone guess what the *thing* you're asking about is post the relevant code that can clearly identify whether it's a dict, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is a very poor question. Apologies. What's a good way to print the type of an object?

Comment: From the level of this question, you would probably be well served to download the free Apple Swift book from the iTunes Book Store and work through some of the examples.  It starts at a pretty basic level and proceeds through some very advanced topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayOfPhotos` in this case is going to be an `NSArray` containing an ordered collection of `NSDictionary`.  An `NSArray` is inherently ordered collection indexed by an integer as you get things out of them in the same order you put them into it.  As opposed to an `NSDictionary` which is an unordered collection indexed by (in this case) an NSString.  The dictionary is unordered because things don't necessarily come out in the same order you put them in, and in fact, come out in an unpredictable order if you were to iterate over all of the items in the dictionary.

To answer the exact question you asked, you would be better put to use:

```
if let photosData = parsedResult as? NSDictionary {
    if let arrayOfPhotos = photosData.valueForKey as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        // At this point, arrayOfPhotos is an array of dictionaries, so we use direct int indexing:
        let firstPhoto = arrayOfPhotos[0]
        let nthPhoto = arrayOfPhotos[n]

        // Both firstPhoto and nthPhoto now have the type [String:AnyObject], or in otherwords
        //  they map a String to anything, anything because "id" is an int, and "name" is a String
        let firstId = firstPhoto["id"] as! Int
        let firstName = firstPhoto["name"] as! String
    }
}
```